# Installing WordPress multisite on a domain with subfolder

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Just moved my WordPress multisite from localhost to live server. The destination folder has two sub directories mydomain.com/dir1/dir2 I'm getting a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error can anyone help me out. I've made all the necessary url updates in the database. Thanks

**wp-config**

```
 /* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com/dir1/dir2');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking how the redirect loop behaves by using browser developers tools. The most common problem is Wordpress set to be on www subdomain and custom .htaccess striping www.

(If it doesn't solve your problem, could you post an example of the loop? Screenshot of developer tools will do just fine.)